# Unable to set TestContext property

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a visual studio 2008 Unit test and I'm getting the following runtime error:

```
Unable to set TestContext property for the class JMPS.PlannerSuite.DataServices.MyUnitTest.  Error:  System.ArgumentException:  Object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapterContext' cannot be converted to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext'
```

I have read that VS 2008 does not properly  update the references to the UnitTestFramework when converting 2005 projects.  My unit test was created in 2008 but it inherits from a base class built in VS 2005.  Is this where my problem is coming from?  Does my base class have to be rebuilt in 2008?  I would rather not do this as it will affect other projects.

In other derived unit tests built in 2005, all that we needed to do was comment out the TestContext property in the derived unit test.  I have tried this in the VS 2008 unit test with no luck.  I have also tried to "new" the TestContext property which gives me a different runtime error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just tried to convert the base class to VS 2008 and now it seems to work.  But, I would rather not do this as it will force other projects to be converted.  So if there is any way around this, that would be great.

Comment: I'm having the same issue in a Test class that I built fresh in VS2008.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem in Visual Studio 2012 when I upgraded an older project (i think 2005).

The Reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework needs to be removed by right clicking it in the Solution Explorer then removing it.

To add the right one:

1. Add New Reference
2. Extensions, find Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, there are likely several
3. Mouse over to display the path, choose the one in ../IDE/PublicAssemblies
4. Clean
5. Rebuild
6. Rerun tests

Comment: This worked well for me in VS 2010 as well.  The path in step 3, if you aren't familiar, is Program Files/Visual Studio (your version, mine was 10)/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies.

Comment: The answer above worked for me. In case you're still battling, try: dbl-click SmartDeviceTestRun.testrunConfig (created when unit test project created) -> Hosts -> pick your platform and Device. Also: r-click test project -> properties -> devices -> select your target device (test project target device should equal actual project's target device).

Comment: I have the same problem and my UTFramework is referenced to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll

for VS 2012

Comment: Works like a charm :-)

Comment: Note that nowadays you might desire to install `MSTest.TestAdapter` and `MSTest.TestFramework` via nuget instead of using the framework reference.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this here in the hopes that it helps someone unit testing a smart device project. I got a very similar error when I first tried to run a unit test for a method in a smart device project I was working on in Visual Studio 2008:

```
Error: System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapterContext' cannot be converted to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext'
```

Googling the error returned results that suggested it was caused by upgrading a test project from Visual Studio 2005 format to 2008, and that the reference to the UnitTestFramework.dll was still for the old version (8.0) and required updating. This did not apply to me as I had not upgraded my test project from VS2005. So I continued searching.

After hours of searching for other causes for the error without success, I stumbled upon the following references in the smart device project:

- Microsoft.WindowsMobile.dll
- Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status.dll

Visual Studio was obtaining these references from the following folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK R2\Managed Libraries
```

However, the smart device project's target platform was the **Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK**. I didn't notice this before as I did not originally create the smart device project. So I removed the references to the two DLLs and readded them from the following folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Managed Libraries
```

After rebuilding the smart device project, running the test method succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Turned out that one of my projects was referencing the 8.0 assemblies and the other was referencing 9.0. The solution compiled, but I got a runtime exception.